# FullCalendar does not bind with Server

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I am working in a project where users create orders from customers and then the users are able to see all the orders in a calendar. Every Order has a detail. Right now I am having troubles in showing the orders that are created. I create my backend in ASP.NET Core with the methods GET, POST, PUT and DELETE and my front end in Angular 12.

My class of Orders in ASP NET Core is:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumer { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public Business Business { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have in my **order.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from 'src/app/models/order';
import { OrdersService } from 'src/app/services/orders.service';
import {CalendarOptions} from '@fullcalendar/angular'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
orders!: Order[];

calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  events: this.getOrders
};

  constructor(private _ordersService: OrdersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOrders();
  }
  
  getOrders(){
  this._ordersService.getOrders().subscribe(data => {
    this.orders= data;
  })
}
}
```

I want it to appear like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K8km.png) but with the values from my database

Comment: So whats your actual question?

Comment: @DaleK I will like to know why it doesn't show the orders from the database

Comment: Based on that C# class, your event data doesn't appear to match what fullCalendar will be expecting. The documentation explains how to name the fields in the event objects you pass to the calendar, and what they should contain - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I will the documentation, but it's there another way to make a calendar in Angular? Because I will like to add the option to click the event and to show all the information of the order

Comment: You can do that with fullCalendar, there is a hook to handle clicking on the event, then you can write some code to display extra info, whatever you want